# problem mixing material-ui elements and code in react javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I constantly have issues trying to use code and material-ui elements in react jsx code.  Here's a code snippet:

```
const icols = 0;
const makeTableRow = (
  x,
  i,
  formColumns,
  handleRemove,
  handleSelect) =>
  <TableRow key={`tr-${i}`}>
    {formColumns.map((y, k) => (
      y.displayColumn ? (<TableCell key={`trc-${k}`}>{x[y.name]}</TableCell>) : null), <-comma added for next line
      y.displayColumn ? (cols+=1) : null)
    )}
    <TableCell>
      <IconButton onClick={() => handleSelect(i)} ><EditIcon fontSize='small'/></IconButton>
      <IconButton onClick={() => handleRemove(i)} ><DeleteForeverIcon fontSize='small' /></IconButton>
    </TableCell>
  </TableRow>
```

I am getting a jsx parsing error, when I add this line above:

```
      y.displayColumn ? (cols+=1) : null)
```

If I remove the comma at the EOL above it, I still get an error.  Basically I can't get a map to exec more than one statement.

If I take out the line and the EOL comma above it, everything works but I don't get a displayed column count, which I require.

I've tried using simple if/else which I am more comfortable with, but I have NEVER been able to get if/else to work in a jsx function.  I want to only create a tablecell for a column w/displayColumn flag set to true, and I want a total count of the displayed columns, so I can use it later on (cols).

Is there a way to accomplish this with an if/else statement?  Then I can have more than 1 statement in the if clause.  The ternary operator only allows 1 statement, and I can't find anywhere what maps limitations are.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: try this:

{formColumns.map((y, k) => {

      y.displayColumn ? 

(cols+=1,return <TableCell key={`trc-${k}`}>{x[y.name]}</TableCell>) :

return  null)}
    )}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. You can open the open the arrow function body in map and put return JSX and do the `cols` increment there. Instead of having two ternary operator checks for the same condition, we can have just one conditional statement.

```js
<TableRow key={`tr-${i}`}>
  {
    formColumns.map((y, k) => {
      if (y.displayColumn) {
        cols += 1;
        return <TableCell key={`trc-${k}`}>{x[y.name]}</TableCell>
      }
      return null
    })
  }
  <TableCell>
    <IconButton onClick={() => handleSelect(i)} ><EditIcon fontSize='small'/></IconButton>
    <IconButton onClick={() => handleRemove(i)} ><DeleteForeverIcon fontSize='small' /></IconButton>
  </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thanks abito.  That worked. I swear I tried the exact same thing but got an error.  Perhaps because I used an else statment? Or did not use a return?  I really want to understand this because I keep running across the same kind of issues.

Comment: Happy to help. This can be confusing sometimes, If you want to have multiple statements inside map, you should have a function body enclosed with curly brackets and have a return statement inside. If it is conditional return, always provide one default return.

Comment: I'm having the same kind of issue here, trying to insert js code amongst material-ui elements: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751068/how-to-insert-a-console-log-in-material-ui-elements-to-verify-object-array-value

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I can't get a map to exec more than one statement.

You can't execute more than one expression inside a arrow function definition, instead use regular declarated functions

```js
    {formColumns.map((y, k) => {
      y.displayColumn ? (cols+=1) : null;
      // Return what you want to render
      return y.displayColumn ? (<TableCell key={`trc-${k}`}>{x[y.name]}</TableCell>) : null
    }}
```

There are only two types of arrow function

```js
arrow_function = () => "i will be returned"
// This way you declare only one expression after the arrow and it is returned
```

and

```js
arrow_function = () => {
    // This is a regular logic function
    text = "i will be" + " returned";
    return text;
}
```

EDIT 1: Add conditionals between JSX

There are two ways i know to do it

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>First form</h2>
      <FirstForm true={true} />
      <hr />
      <h2>Second form</h2>
      <SecondForm true={false} />
    </div>
  )
}

const FirstForm = props => {
  // This way is just a ternary conditional
  return (
    <div>
      {props.true
        ? <span className="success">True condition matched</span>
        : <span className="danger">False condition matched</span>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
const SecondForm = props => {
  // This way uses a anonymous function executed in runtime
  return (
    <div>
      {(() => {
        let message = "Hello";
        message += " World, from an auto executed anonymous function";
        return (
        <span className={props.true?"success":"danger"}>{message}</span>
        )
      })()}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.success {
  color: darkgreen;
}
.danger {
  color: #5e181b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This shows me what I can't do, which I appreciate.  But I've *tried* to use normal javascript functions.  When I do I get errors when I try to include material-ui elements in it.  Can you SHOW me what would work?  I can't get if/else statements to work w/material-ui elements.

Comment: @aaava you mean you want if/else statements inside jsx? It's posible.

Comment: Well, if it is, I have not been able to find any examples of this on the web. I have another question with the same kind of issue, where I cannot add any javascript statements to a set of material-ui elements.  No matter HOW I frame it, I get syntax errors.  After 20 years of C# and Java, one would think this wouldn't be so difficult!

Even the answer above only has an if statement.  Whenever I try to add an 'else' I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok psiro, so I looked at your examples, which all work *in your situation*.  However, as soon as I apply one to my scenario, I still get a syntax error.  Like here:

```
<TableBody>
  {(() => {
    console.log('data = ' + JSON.Stringify(data, null, 2) + '.'));
    return ((data.length > 0) ? (
    data.map((x, i) => row(
    x,
    i,
    formColumns,
    handleRemove,
    handleSelect,
    editIdx
    ))) : (<TableRow><TableCell colSpan={`${cols}`}>No Data</TableCell></TableRow>) )
  })()}
</TableBody>
```

And this is the problem I have w/anonymous functions.  They create unmaintainable code.  I am not doing anything different than your example.  Just TWO js statements inside the code you presented.  Your code works, mine returns a syntax error.

And why do I even NEED a double-anonymous function to have 2 simple js statements inside an if statement?  Why does your code work, and mine not?

Addendum:

Ok, so I made some inferences based on your code and realized I had added yet ANOTHER anonymous function (the map statement) into the code.  I reworked it into this, which compiled:

```
  {(() => {
    console.log('data = ' + JSON.Stringify(data, null, 2) + '.');
    if (data.length > 0) {
    return (data.map((x, i) => row(x, i, formColumns, handleRemove, handleSelect, editIdx)))
  }
  return(<TableRow><TableCell colSpan={`${cols}`}>No Data</TableCell></TableRow>)
  })()}
```

The fact that it looks completely unmaintainable is irrelevant I guess.  But it doesn't matter because it STILL doesn't work!  Now I get a 'JSON.stringify is not a function' at runtime, which is ridiculous of course.  Why can't I get a simple console.log to work in reactjs?

ADDENDUM:

Ok, I fixed the issue thanks to all the help.  For anyone else that has an issue w/multiple statements inside an anonymous function, if you want to do it, you need to add a return statement so the function knows what result to return.

```
<TableBody>
  {(() => {
    console.log('data = ' + data + '.');
    if (data.length > 0) {
    return (data.map((x, i) => row(x, i, formColumns, handleRemove, handleSelect, editIdx)))
  }
  return(<TableRow><TableCell colSpan={`${cols}`}>No Data</TableCell></TableRow>)
  })()}     
</TableBody>
```

That includes when you have an anonymous function *inside* another anonymous function. Hope this helps anyone else having this problem.

Comment: tbh i never had any issue handling these things, i'd need to more context and play with the code to see why it doesn't work.
Also it's probably a typo but your code says JSON.Stringify instead of JSON.stringify

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo when copying it.  Wasn't in the code like that.  I truly appreciate your help w/this.  I'm just not a big fan of anonymous functions.  I think they make code more difficult to maintain, but I'm obviously in the minority! If vscode were had better support for locating matching parens/curly brackets/etc it would probably help.