# How to insert a console.log in material-ui elements to verify object/array/value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am getting an error from react js when I execute this code snippet:

```
<TableBody>
  { (data.length > 0) ? (
    data.map((x, i) => row(
    x,
    i,
    formColumns,
    handleRemove,
    handleSelect,
    editIdx
    ))) : (<TableRow><TableCell colSpan={`${cols}`}>No Data</TableCell></TableRow>)}
</TableBody>
```

The value of 'data' is an empty array [], which SHOULD return a length of 0
But it passes the length test somehow.

Instead I get an error 'data.map is not a function'.

I am trying to insert:

```
console.log('data = ' + JSON.Stringify(data, null, 2) + '.'))
```

in the code somewhere, so I can see what it's doing.  When I check the data GOING IN to the Table, it's = [].  So why is the length not working, and what do I need to do to place javascript code inside a set of material-ui elements?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
{ console.log('data = ' + JSON.Stringify(data, null, 2) + '.')) }
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is, I never GET to the location where you place the console.log statement. I need it BEFORE the 'row.map' line.

One of the things I tried last night was to wrap the console.log in curly brackets.  I STILL rec'd an error.  


Could you show how to put the console.log statement BEFORE the row.map (ie right after the the <TableBody> statement. This is where I get an error now matter HOW I try to frame the js statement.

Comment: Ok, then may you provide https://codesandbox.io/ with a working fragment of your code?